# android studio capture image faster

Tags: android, camera, handler, surfaceview, capture

I have a camera application project and I want to take two photos at 200 ms intervals.
but usually takes pictures at intervals of 450-550 ms. How can I take photos faster?
I open camera surface view and when ı push to button handler start the timer and when time reach to 60000-millisecond camera capture first image and after 200 ms capture the second image

### [Heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsIE9.jpg)

```
public class camerax_timer extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextureView textureView;
TextView editColor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camerax_timer);
    editColor=findViewById(R.id.textcolor);
    textureView = findViewById(R.id.view_finder);

    textureView.post((Runnable)(new Runnable()
    {
        public final void run()
        {
            startCamera();
        }
    }));

    textureView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, 
    int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
        {
            updateTransform();
        }
    });

    Button button_ileri=findViewById(R.id.ileri_image);
    button_ileri.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent =new Intent(camerax_timer.this,veri_hesaplama.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void startCamera()
{
    PreviewConfig.Builder previewConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder();

    Preview preview = new Preview(previewConfig.build());

    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output)
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) textureView.getParent();
            parent.removeView(textureView);
            parent.addView(textureView, 0);

            textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
            updateTransform();
        }
    });

    ImageCaptureConfig.Builder imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder();

    final ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig.build());

    final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            imageCapture.takePicture(new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
                                    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.img1);
                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageProxyToBitmap(image));
                                    imageView.setRotation(rotationDegrees);
                                    image.close();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 60000);



                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            imageCapture.takePicture(new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCaptureSuccess(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
                                    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.img2);
                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(imageProxyToBitmap(image));
                                    imageView.setRotation(rotationDegrees);
                                    image.close(); 
                                
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }, 60200);

            }
    });

    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imageCapture);
}


private void updateTransform()
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    float centerX = textureView.getWidth() / 2f;
    float centerY = textureView.getHeight() / 2f;
    float rotationDegrees = 0;
    matrix.postRotate(-rotationDegrees, centerX, centerY);
    textureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
private Bitmap imageProxyToBitmap(ImageProxy image)
{
    ImageProxy.PlaneProxy planeProxy = image.getPlanes()[0];
    ByteBuffer buffer = planeProxy.getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every device camera and every device OS has its time to be ready to take a photo, expecially after taking another photo.
The best solution for you is to take a video and then load and analyze it.
To register a video, you can use the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) class.
To get single frames from the video, you should use the  [wseemann.media.FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) library, because the standard [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever) is a little bugged.
This library allows you to get single frame this way:

```
tempImage = retriever.getFrameAtTime(time, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

where

- "tempImage" is a Bitmap,
- "retriever" is a FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever,
- "time" is the time you want to take the frame from in microseconds.